# This question was closed as not appropriate on this site; so why can't I delete it?

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-questions

[After strenuous exercise, can my heart rate stay elevated even while sleeping?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/27824/after-strenuous-exercise-can-my-heart-rate-stay-elevated-even-while-sleeping)

Well, the title says it all, really.  I asked the question.  It got one answer.  The answer got one upvote.  Yet the question has been closed as not being on-topic for this site.

Yet even though the question is inappropriate, I can't delete it, apparently because it was answered, even though it *shouldn't* have been answered since it's an inappropriate question.

What's the rationale for keeping around bad questions?  To permanently serve as a bad example?

Comment: I'm on the fence if it's off-topic or not. I think it could changed to be on-topic. That point aside, only you and users with enough rep to close/reopen can see it so it doesn't quite serve as an example. I believe the largest reason you can't delete it because you'd cause a user to lose rep.

Comment: I do think it's an interesting question though. Maybe we could edit and reopen instead of deleting!

Comment: @C.Lange I don't know how I could possibly make it on-topic.  As for losing rep...actually, I just noticed that the user who answered it is deleted, so the only person losing rep here would be me, and I don't care about losing that 10 points, even if it's a staggering 10% of my rep here.  

Comment: I noticed they were deleted too. Regardless, it looks like one of the mods took notice and deleted it for you.

Comment: I flagged it with the explanation that the answerer was deleted.